# Django colon syntax in template tags: only in newer versions?

Tags: python, django

I just deployed an application to a new server, and although I'm using virtualenv, I had to install a new environment on the production server, which has a different architecture.

Anyway, I received no TemplateSytaxErrors in development, but on the production server, I get:

```
Exception Type:     TemplateSyntaxError
Exception Value:    Caught SyntaxError while rendering: invalid syntax (views.py, line 25)
```

The offending line is:

```
{% url admin:password_change as password_change_url %}
```

Upon removing that line, the TemplateSyntaxError hops to the next line that has a colon in it (and lets other template tags work fine).

So my question is this: is there some discrepancy in versions of Python/Django that would allow or disallow the namespacing syntax?

The template tags are in django-grappelli (http://code.google.com/p/django-grappelli/), so I'd rather not go through their code and rewrite all the template tags.

**Development server:**

- 32-bit Debian
- Python 2.5.5
- Django 1.2.1

**Production server:**

- 64-bit CentOS
- Python 2.4.3
- Django 1.2.1

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On closer inspection, I realized this wasn't the offending line, even though it was highlighted in the traceback:

```
{% url admin:password_change as password_change_url %}
```

The line was actually in my views.py, where I used the ternary operator (`"this" if condition else "that"`). Little did I know, this syntax is only supported in Python 2.5 and up.

Problem solved.